# X is a prevariety. Is diagonal $\Delta$=$\{(x,y)\in X\times X\;|\;x=y\}$ locally closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let X be a prevariety. Prove for any prevariety Y and any two regular maps $f, g : Y \to X$, the subset $\{y\in Y :f(y)=g(y)\}\subset Y$ is locally closed. Here locally closed means the subset is an intersection of a closed set and an open set. Or it is closed in an open subset.

Actually I try to prove this by showing that the diagonal $\Delta$=$\{(x,y)\in X\times X|x=y\}$ is locally closed? And the above subset is the inverse image of $\Delta$, so it is also locally closed. The way I prove $\Delta$ is locally closed is like this.

Firs pick up finite charts that cover $X\times X$. Then since each chart $U_i\times U_i$ is isomorphic to some algebraic set, the intersection of $\Delta$ and $U_i\times U_i$ (denote as $\Delta_i$)has closed image in the algebraic set. So $\Delta_i$ is closed in $ U_i\times U_i$, hence is locally closed. $\Delta$=$\bigcup$ $\Delta_i$, but how should I show $\Delta$ is locally closed?

Does there exists another way to prove? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what locally closed means?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oh, sorry, I mean it is an intersection of an open set and closed set. Or you can think as closed in a neighborhood.

Comment: It's a standard result that the diagonal is always an immersion. See, for instance, page 41 in http://attach3.bdwm.net/attach/0Announce/groups/GROUP_0/PersonalCorpus/OldCorpus/S/Sonnet/D3FD9876D/AAB079045/fulei.pdf